# How to add a second project to UWP solution to respond to tile clicks only

Tags: uwp

So my UWP app is a bit sluggish to load as it has grown rather feature-rich.
One of the features is the ability to create a tile in the start menu and copy content into the clipboard when the user clicks the tile.

Currently, that is done through the main UWP app, which needs to start and then respond to the tile click activation. Rather sluggish when the app is not already loaded.

Is there a way (e.g. akin to the Background task approach) to tie the tile to a smaller, faster-ready component of the overall solution that would just respond to the tile click, nothing else?

Still needs to ship in the total UWP bundle as some content might be inside the app's filespace.

Comment: Have you checked my reply about tile click event?

Answer (score 0):

The tile click event can only be handled through `Application.OnActivated`. There is `Launch` in Enum [ActivationKind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.activation.activationkind?view=winrt-22621#fields) which means the user launched the app or tapped a content tile. You cannot handle tile click event in Background task or component, your app must be launched.

Comment: Thanks Junjie! Will change the activation response as per my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up changing the activation response of the UWP app to perform the requested action first, before even loading the UI, in a thread, to ensure that the user gets the requested action before the app UI was available. Seems the best compromise. Any thoughts?